# Kernel of ring homomorphism $k[X,Y] \rightarrow k[t^2, t^3]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $k$ be a field, $f: k[X,Y] \rightarrow k[t^2, t^3]$,

$X \mapsto t^3, Y\mapsto t^2$.

I would like to verify that

$\ker f = (X^2 - Y^3)$. It is easy to see that $X^2 - Y^3 \in \ker f$ and therefore $(X^2 - Y^3) \subseteq \ker f$, but I struggle with proving $\ker f \subseteq (X^2- Y^3)$.

**context**: I want to show that $(X^2-Y^3)$ is prime in $k[X,Y]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $p$ is in the kernel. Then by polynomial division you can write $p=q(X^2-Y^3)+r$ where no term of $r$ has degree $\ge 2$ in $X$, and clearly $r$ is then also in the kernel.

Now $r$ consists of terms of the form $aY^n$ and terms of the form $aXY^n$. Under $f$ the former terms become $at^{2n}$ and the latter terms become $at^{2n+3}$. But $t^{2n}$ and $t^{2n+3}$ are all linearly independent over $k$ in $k[t]$, so the only way for $f(r)$ to be zero is if all the coefficients of $r$ vanish.

In other words, $r=0$ and $p=(X^2-Y^3)q$.

Comment: I do not completely understand the part about the polynomial division. I assume that you are doing it "in $X$", right (since the degree of $X$ matters)? But as far as I know $k[X,Y] = (k[Y])[X]$ should not be euclidean, because $k[Y]$ is not a field...

Comment: @CHwC: The polynomial division works well enough in this case nonetheless: Just repeatedly rewrite a term $aX^{n+2}Y^m$ to $aX^nY^{m+3}+(X^2-Y^3)\cdot aX^nY^m$ until the exponent of $X$ is $0$ or $1$.

Comment: This works because the leading coefficient of $X^2-Y^3 \in k[Y][X]$ is a unit in $k[Y]$.